# How can I find out where a Perl module is installed?

Tags: perl, path, module, config

How do get the path of a installed Perl module by name,
e.g. `Time::HiRes`?

I want this just because I have to run my perl script on different nodes of a SGE Grid Engine system. Sometimes, even run as other username.

I can use CPAN.pm to install packages for myself, but it is not so easy to install for other users without chmod 666 on folders.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Do you need it in another program or do you just want to see it on the command line?

Comment: By far the easiest way is described in [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561396/137948), i.e. use `perl -d` and then type `M`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note**: This solution proposes use of a (self-authored) *utility* that you must *download*. While it offers what I believe to be helpful features, installing a third-party solution first is *not an option for everyone*.

---

I've created [**`whichpm`**](https://github.com/mklement0/whichpm), a **cross-platform CLI** (Linux, macOS, Window) that **locates installed Perl modules by module (package) name**, and optionally reports information about them, including detection of accidental duplicates.

**Examples**

```
# Locate the Data::Dumper module.
$ whichpm Data::Dumper
/usr/lib/perl/5.18/Data/Dumper.pm

# Locate the Data::Dumper module, and also print
# version information and core-module status.
$ whichpm -v Data::Dumper
Data::Dumper    2.145   core>=5.005 /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Data/Dumper.pm

# Locate the Data::Dumper module and open it in your system's default text
# editor.
$ whichpm -e Data::Dumper

# Look for accidental duplicates of the Foo::Bar module.
# Normally, only 1 path should be returned.
$ whichpm -a Foo::Bar
/usr/lib/perl/5.18/Foo/Bar.pm
./Foo/Bar.pm

# Print the paths of all installed modules.
$ whichpm -a
```

### Installation

Prerequisites: **Linux**, **macOS**, or **Windows**, with **Perl v5.4.50 or higher** installed.

#### Installation from the npm registry

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or [io.js](https://iojs.org/) installed, install [the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whichpm) as follows:

```
[sudo] npm install whichpm -g
```

#### Manual installation (macOS and Linux)

- Download [the CLI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/whichpm/stable/bin/whichpm) as `whichpm`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x whichpm`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (OSX) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

Comment: Thanks, @Galaxy. The code you link to is definitely handy. _This_ solution adds: detecting case-inexact names on OS X and Windows, core-module status, finding duplicates, and the ability to open modules directly for editing.

Answer (score 103):

`perl -MTime::HiRes -e 'print $INC{"Time/HiRes.pm"}'` or `perldoc -l Time::HiRes`

Comment: perldoc only works for those setupped.

the first works for all, but typing the name 2 times is a bit boring.

Comment: If the locate database doesn't have it, for whatever reason, `find /usr/ -path '*/Time/HiRes.pm'`.

Comment: That doesn't tell you where Perl is looking for the file, though.  My Perl modules are in ~/perl/install, for example.

Comment: Well, in my situation, user files all in NFS path, and locate just exclude NFS.
Since the `PERL5LIB` is a bit long on that system, `find` is not a good way.

Comment: For Windows, might need to use double-quotes on the outside, single quotes on the inside. Command as given errors:
`Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.` on Windows 7.

Command: `perl -MTime::HiRes -e "print $INC{'Time/HiRes.pm'}"` works.

Comment: `perldoc only works for those setupped` I wonder what are setupped modules. Both commands work for modules installed with `pacman` or with `carton` (`carton exec ...`). Also, you can do `perl -MTime::HiRes -e 'for my $k (keys %INC) { print "$k: $INC{$k}\n"; }'`.

Answer (score 36):

Mostly I use `perldoc` to get a location:

```
$ perldoc -l Module
```

You can also get module details with the `cpan` tool that comes with Perl:

```
$ cpan -D Time::HiRes
Time::HiRes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    High resolution time, sleep, and alarm
    J/JH/JHI/Time-HiRes-1.9719.tar.gz
    /usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.0/lib/5.10.0/darwin-2level/Time/HiRes.pm
    Installed: 1.9711
    CPAN:      1.9719  Not up to date
    Andrew Main (Zefram) (ZEFRAM)
    zefram@fysh.org
```

It even works on modules that you haven't installed:

```
$ cpan -D Win32::Process
Win32::Process
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Interface to Win32 Process functions
    J/JD/JDB/Win32-Process-0.14.tar.gz
    Installed: 
    CPAN:      0.14  Not up to date
    Jan Dubois (JDB)
    jand@activestate.com
```

I think maybe I need an XML option like svn.

Comment: But, just everything THAT on CPAN.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: What if you write a package such as FOO::Bar and put it in `PERL5LIB` ?

Answer (score 12):

If need to find which modules are actually used by your script you can use perl debuggers `M` command:

```
[ivan@server ~]$ perl -d your_script.pl
...

Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.

DB M
'AutoLoader.pm' => '5.60 from /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/AutoLoader.pm'
'Carp.pm' => '1.04 from /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Carp.pm'
...
```

This will help in case when you have modules with same names but in different folder.

Comment: This is the best answer because it's very simple and doesn't require any additional software to be downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

I just find another one:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=568730

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'print map { sprintf( "%20s : %s\n", $_, $INC{$_} ) } sort keys %INC; print "\n'$1' version : $'$1'::VERSION\n\n"' | perl "-M$1"
```

the script just print out everything in %INC when you run `perl -MSTH::STH`

eg:

```
$ whichpm CGI       
              CGI.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/CGI.pm
         CGI/Util.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/CGI/Util.pm
             Carp.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/Carp.pm
         Exporter.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/Exporter.pm
         constant.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/constant.pm
         overload.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/overload.pm
           strict.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/strict.pm
             vars.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/vars.pm
         warnings.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/warnings.pm warnings/register.pm : /System/Library/Perl/5.8.6/warnings/register.pm

CGI version : 3.05
```

Comment: If you just want the version, it's probably easiest to type `perl -MYour::Module\ 999`.  If the version number is less than 999, it will be printed.

Comment: Okay, but no upvotes unless you can explain what that's doing.

Comment: Might it not be easier to just do this in Perl rather than wrapping a shell script around it?

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the [V](https://metacpan.org/pod/V) module.

Just install it from CPAN or by installing the package `libv-perl` on Debian or Ubuntu.

Then use it like this:

```
$ perl -MV=DBI
DBI
    /Users/michiel/.plenv/versions/5.24.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/darwin-2level/DBI.pm: 1.636
```

Other output example:

```
$ perl -MV=Time::HiRes
Time::HiRes
    /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Time/HiRes.pm: 1.9725
```

Answer (score 2):

`perldoc -l` works for me

```
perldoc -l "File::Find"
/opt/perl_32/lib/5.8.8/File/Find.pm
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the simplest way is `perldoc -l Time::HiRes`.

---

If that isn't available for some reason, here's a pragmatic solution:

Step 1: Instantiate the module in your script...

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use Time::HiRes();
new Time::HiRes();
```

Step 2: Execute the script with the Perl graphical debugger...

```
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:~/perl ## tell perl where to look for "Devel"/"ptkdb.pm"
perl -d:ptkdb (yourscript.pl)
```

Step 3: `Step in` to the `new` call.

**The full pathname of the module will be displayed on the title-bar of the debugger window.**

---

Another approach that might be useful would be to search all of the folders in `$PERL5LIB`.

Comment: `perldoc -l` will not show your homemade .`pm` files that without `pod`.

Comment: @Galaxy if you don't know where your homemade .pm files are then how are you including them?

Comment: I setup serval PERL5LIB locations, and I need to know which one is working for that pm file.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Ivan's answer that allows this to be run without installing additional software the following will use Perl's debugger to find a specific module (or modules):

```
perl -de 'use <Module Name>;'
```

For Example:

```
perl -de 'use DBD::Oracle;'
```

Output:

```
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

DBD::Oracle::CODE(0x27f81d8)(/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBD/Oracle.pm:113):
113:            $ENV{PERL_BADFREE} = 0;
  DB<1> q
```

Comment: For me it says, "Debugged program terminated." Why would it step into `use`?

Answer (score 0):

In OSX you can use:

> perl -e 'print join("\n",@INC)'

The result should be the location of your lib.

Then add this code in your Perl code:

```
use lib '/your/folder/location/to/lib';
```