# How to find the location of a Perl module on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, perl

We moved everything on our old server to a new server. One of the websites on our new server uses a Perl back-end. When I go to this Perl site in my browser it throws a 500 internal server error. When I run the Perl script from the command line like this:

`perl -wc login.pl`

I get this error:

`Can't locate LoadINC.pm`

and at the top of login.pl there is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN { use LoadINC; }

...
```

So it looks like that `LoadINC` Perl module is missing from our new server.

The old server is still running and doesn't have this issue. So my thought is to locate the `LoadINC` module on the old server and then put it in the same place on the new server. Or is there a better approach? Is the module hidden in some binary file? Are the places to look for Perl modules not the same on both servers?

One other thing to note, the Perl version on the old server is 5.8.8 and the version on the new server is 5.16.3.

Comment: `BEGIN { use LoadINC; }` really doesn't make sense. It should probably just be `use LoadINC;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out where a Perl module is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557959/how-can-i-find-out-where-a-perl-module-is-installed)

Comment: @Andy Lester, That might answer the question in the title, but the Question asks an entirely different question

Answer (score 5):

> *How to find the location of a Perl module on a Linux server?*

```
perl -mFoo::Bar -le'print $INC{"Foo/Bar.pm"}'
```

or

```
perldoc -lm Foo::Bar
```

In this case,

```
perl -mLoadINC -le'print $INC{"LoadINC.pm"}'
```

or

```
perldoc -lm LoadINC
```

---

> *So my thought is to locate the LoadINC module on the old server and then put it in the same place on the new server. Or is there a better approach?*

How are we suppose to know how to install your module?

Most modules are installed using one of

```
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

or

```
perl Build.PL
./Build test
./Build install
```

Simply copying the file might work, but there are a number of reasons why it might not. On the plus side, you'll immediately know if it worked or not in most cases.

---

> *Are the places to look for Perl modules not the same on both servers?*

The list of directories searched will definitely be different (given the difference in versions), though both builds may have directories in common.

Architecture-independent modules should be installed in the directory named by the output of the following command:

```
perl -V:installprivlib
```

Answer (score 2):

`use LoadINC` will look for a file called `LoadINC.pm`. Perl searches the directories listed in `@INC` for modules. You can see them with

```
perl -wle 'print for @INC'
```

`@INC` is composed from a compiled-in list of directories, the contents of the environment variable `PERL5LIB`, any `-I` options on the command line, and whatever changes the running code may have made.

You can ask [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) for the location of a file matching a module name:

```
perldoc -lm LoadINC
```

If you can load the module, you can also ask perl itself:

```
perl -wle 'use LoadINC (); print $INC{"LoadINC.pm"}'
```

([`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC) is a hash that maps the base name of a loaded module to its path.)

Comment: That might answer the question in the title, but the Question asks an entirely different question

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
$ perldoc -lm open
/usr/lib/perl5/5.24.1/open.pm
```

Or the sledgehammer method:

```
$ locate -r open.pm$
/usr/lib/perl5/5.24.1/open.pm
```

But [TMTOWTDI](http://www.symkat.com/find-a-perl-modules-path).

Comment: That might answer the question in the title, but the Question asks an entirely different question